# DBIx::Class undefined value exception when trying to use ->create()

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, catalyst, dbix-class

I'm trying to create a new row using DBIx::Class from within Catalyst, with the following code:

```
$c->model('Session')->resultset('UserPreference')->create(
                {
                 appname => 'rss_reader',
                 username => $username,
                 data => $data,
                },
               );
```

But, I hit this error every time:

```
Caught exception in App::Controller::rss->dbo "Can't call method "resolve" on an undefined value at /etg/source/Linux/pkg/perl-5.8.8/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/DBIx/Class/Row.pm line 1309."
```

I see a few mailing lists talking about this error being thrown as an incorrect blanket error when the query fails for whatever reason (perms, constraints,etc.), but it looks just fine AND even running with DBIC_TRACE=1, I don't even see the generated query in my console.

I should mention I don't think there's something bad with the permissions,etc. since using the database handle manually works:

```
my $stm=$c->model("Session")->storage->dbh->prepare("insert into user_preferences (username,appname,data) values ('mphillip','rss_reader','cookies')"); $stm->execute();
```

Comment: report this as a bug in DBIx::Class, at least error message should be friendlier

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `update_or_create` instead of `create`? If a row exists `create` will fail.